# How to control the zoom in and zoom out?

Tags: modeling, interface

I am doing a model and the speed at which I am zooming in and out is very fast. I mean one scroll and I am inside the model, looking at faces and one scroll in opposite direction, my model appears in complete ISO view.
How to control this? Any settings are getting messed up?

Comment: Are you dealing with a very large or very small model?

Comment: yes it is kind of very tiny model

Comment: Try using a different scale. Instead of meters (the default) try working in mm.

Answer (score 1):

1. Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click and hold middle mouse button and move the mouse forward/backward for more precise zooming.
2. Left <kbd>Alt</kbd> + click middle mouse button on the object you want to focus on to reset the zoom-focus on this object.

Comment: Hi. Yes, I am aware about zooming in with control key but my major problem is how all of sudden it started acting weird. Everything was ok till half-way. I did change few setting for orientation and all but I messed up with some shortcut or preferences and this is causing a lot of irritation.